SQL query to get records based on priority of values in 1 column and overall 3 columns
I have a requirement to get the id value from a table which is like below:



PkId
Id
State
Date1
Date2




GUID1
122
P
03-04-2022
01-01-2022


GUID2
122
A
04-05-2022
01-01-2022


GUID3
122
T
02-10-2022
01-01-2022


GUID4
123
V
01-04-2021
12-10-2020


GUID5
123
A
02-06-2021
12-10-2020



Here PkId is the primary key, another column Id which can be repeated, and 3 more columns. My requirement is to have the output based on the priority of values in:
Column state:
Priority : A > P > V > T > Others

Column Date1 most recent
Column Date2 most recent

I have tried using CTE suggested by some other posts in StackOverflow which shows the solutions for priority related issues but none seem to help me. I am expecting Id field from the table which I need to later query in another table to see if it exists in the new table.

Sorting State Priority is an issue because in alphabetical order T comes before V. Maybe we need a case to give priority letters numerical values so they sort correctly.

So you're just after an ORDER BY? A CTE won't help you there; you can't order your results in a CTE. The ORDER BY goes at end of your query.

Attaching the expected result will help out a lot, since it's not clear if you want only one row, one row per "group" or all rows ordered by something

We cannot fix code unless you post code here to actually fix

"I have tried using CTE ..."  Where???  We don't see your query posted with this question.

Note that tables have rows and columns. (Not records or fields.)

This solution uses a CASE expression in the ORDER BY Clause to give the [State] characters numerical values that can be sorted according to your needs. The top ID (122) is returned for use in other queries as requested.
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM Example
ORDER BY 
  CASE [State]
  WHEN 'A' THEN 1
  WHEN 'P' THEN 2
  WHEN 'V' THEN 3
  WHEN 'T' THEN 4
  ELSE 5 END ,  
  Date1 desc, Date2 desc

fiddle
This is how the records are sorted:



PkId
Id
State
Date1
Date2




GUID2
122
A
2022-04-05
2022-01-01


GUID5
123
A
2021-02-06
2020-12-10


GUID1
122
P
2022-03-04
2022-01-01


GUID4
123
V
2021-01-04
2020-12-10


GUID3
122
T
2022-02-10
2022-01-01




A good answer explains the solution.

That's a case expression, it returns a value. (Case statements are used in stored procedures for conditional execution of code.)
